Just i am using python libraray torchvision and i want to convert it into the pyinstaller but it is not converting
Just I am using python library torchvision and I want to convert it into the pyinstaller but it is not converting.
The following errors result:
(LPM_env) F:\LPM Environment>auto-py-to-exe
49104 WARNING: lib not found: torch_cpu.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\torchvision\_C.pyd
49178 WARNING: lib not found: c10.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\torchvision\_C.pyd
49342 WARNING: lib not found: torch_python.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\torch\_C_flatbuffer.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
50148 WARNING: lib not found: swscale-5-a27d1997.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\video\reformatter.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
50430 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\video\codeccontext.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
50554 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\utils.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
50711 WARNING: lib not found: avcodec-58-ef69f9bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\subtitles\subtitle.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
51019 WARNING: lib not found: avcodec-58-ef69f9bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\subtitles\codeccontext.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
51086 WARNING: lib not found: avformat-58-ab7200bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\stream.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
51144 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\stream.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
51152 WARNING: lib not found: avcodec-58-ef69f9bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\stream.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
51724 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\frame.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
51849 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\filter\pad.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
51853 WARNING: lib not found: avfilter-7-90346677.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\filter\pad.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
52087 WARNING: lib not found: avfilter-7-90346677.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\filter\graph.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
52202 WARNING: lib not found: avfilter-7-90346677.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\filter\filter.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
52326 WARNING: lib not found: avfilter-7-90346677.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\filter\context.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
52557 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\dictionary.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
52849 WARNING: lib not found: avcodec-58-ef69f9bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\data\stream.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
53031 WARNING: lib not found: avformat-58-ab7200bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\container\pyio.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
53096 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\container\pyio.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
53163 WARNING: lib not found: avformat-58-ab7200bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\container\output.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
53235 WARNING: lib not found: avcodec-58-ef69f9bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\container\output.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
53301 WARNING: lib not found: avformat-58-ab7200bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\container\input.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
53366 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\container\input.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
53375 WARNING: lib not found: avcodec-58-ef69f9bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\container\input.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
53434 WARNING: lib not found: avformat-58-ab7200bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\container\core.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
54122 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\audio\codeccontext.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
54246 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\video\frame.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
54362 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\video\format.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
54486 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\error.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
54617 WARNING: lib not found: avcodec-58-ef69f9bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\packet.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
54692 WARNING: lib not found: avformat-58-ab7200bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\format.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
54858 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\codec\context.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
54866 WARNING: lib not found: avcodec-58-ef69f9bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\codec\context.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
54981 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\codec\codec.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
54990 WARNING: lib not found: avcodec-58-ef69f9bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\codec\codec.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
55114 WARNING: lib not found: avfilter-7-90346677.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\audio\resampler.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
55231 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\audio\layout.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
55347 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\audio\frame.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
55355 WARNING: lib not found: avcodec-58-ef69f9bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\audio\frame.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
55471 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\audio\format.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
55593 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\audio\fifo.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
55718 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\logging.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
55784 WARNING: lib not found: avformat-58-ab7200bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\_core.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
55850 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56-70aa9aa7.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\_core.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
55850 WARNING: lib not found: swscale-5-a27d1997.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\_core.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
55859 WARNING: lib not found: avcodec-58-ef69f9bd.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\_core.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
55859 WARNING: lib not found: swresample-3-6975e3c3.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\_core.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
55859 WARNING: lib not found: avdevice-58-1b474226.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\_core.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
55859 WARNING: lib not found: avfilter-7-90346677.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\av\_core.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
55933 WARNING: lib not found: torch_cpu.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\torchvision\image.pyd
56055 WARNING: lib not found: c10.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\torchvision\image.pyd
60755 WARNING: lib not found: torch_python.dll dependency of f:\lpm environment\lpm_env\lib\site-packages\torch\_C.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

How can I correct this?

do not use virtual env, install auto-py-to-exe on the main env and convert it from there

since you are using torchvision and you've saying you are unable to change to pyinstaller right?
I think there is some errors in the installing process you may check the dll's and try resetting the virtual environment
or you can check in the bin folder where all the downloaded packages are stored
this is my point of view...

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
